# error in create object of class

Tags: android

I have my Spinner which is an object of the class SpinnerAdapter.
I try to create the object but there is an errors I try to solve it but I can not.

Here is a picture of error that happened:

[image]

Comment: Please check whether import OnItemSelectedListener class or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either delete the import `android.widget.SpinnerAdapter`, or change your Classname to something like `CustomAdapter` (and you'll see that the instantiated object will just remain an interface (which should be your concrete class), so change that as well)

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails to compile simply because `SpinnerAdapter` is an interface, and as you know, you can't instantiate an interface. You should use one of the classes that implement `SpinnerAdapter`. You can find more information in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: ArrayAdapter<T>, BaseAdapter, CursorAdapter, ResourceCursorAdapter, SimpleAdapter, SimpleCursorAdapter which one u prefer for my example

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a naming conflict with the standard Android interface [SpinnerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html). To make sure your own class `SpinnerAdapter` is used, make sure to prefix it with the full package name. Getting rid of the `android.widget.SpinnerAdapter` import should work too.

To avoid any and all confusion, you might want to simply change the name of your own adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
```

Please check above import.

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut that will save you time : `CTRL + SHIFT + O` in Eclipse (will organize the imports of the current file in the editor). Try it and see what else needs to be fixed in your code.

A combo I like instead of doing a save (real fast to type when you're used to it):

- `CTRL + SHIFT + O` : organize imports
- `CTRL + SHIFT + F` : format code
- `CTRL + SHIFT + S` : save all opened files